# SHP file reading getting error in R

Tags: r, rgdal

Hi I am trying to read and plot on a custom shape file in R which is not a map. 
This is the code I use and the error I get in return:

```
library(rgdal)
mySHP<- choose.files()
myFile<- readOGR(mySHP)
```

> Error in ogrListLayers(dsn = dsn) : Cannot open data source

Comment: you have to split path and filename, iirc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file is a shapefile, you need to specify the `dsn` which is the directory where is saved the shapefile and `layer` which is the name of the shapefile without the extension. You cannot really do it with `choose.files`. At least not that simply.

```
myFile <- readOGR(dsn='path.to.folder', layer='nameOfShapefile')
```

Comment: Hi Sebastien, Thanks for your reply! I did what you said too and now I get this error. On the side note my file is an shp file and shows up fine on mapshaper.org. This is the error I get now:myFile <- readOGR(dsn='C:\Users\Sahib\Documents\bradenradar\Body_polygon (1)', layer='
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U"
>                   body_polygon')

Comment: You are working on windows, you should reverse all the slash: `C:/Users/Sahib/Documents...`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sebastien apparently double slash ended up working for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good. Can you accept the answer. This is the way to thank helpers on stackoverflow...